# В чём смысл уязвимости Meltdown?

Tags: безопасность, cpu, уязвимости, микроархитектура

Недавно стало известно об уязвимости Meltdown, которая затрагивает большинство процессоров Intel. В чём она заключается? Как функционирует атака? Как можно сдетектировать атаку и/или защититься от неё?

Comment: Про Spectre https://geektimes.ru/post/297031/

Comment: Интересно, что проблема в принципе известна уже более 10 лет. См., например, [D.J. Bernstein. Cache-timing attacks on AES](https://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf)  (нашел ссылку в [CACHE MISSING FOR FUN AND PROFIT](http://www.daemonology.net/papers/htt.pdf), в свою очередь из [“Ooh Aah... Just a Little Bit” : A small amount of side channel can go a long
way](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/161.pdf) от 2014-го года)

Comment: @unsetName: Очень неожиданно, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 45):

Смотрите, в чём дело.

У многих современных процессоров есть так называемое *спекулятивное выполнение*. Что это такое?

Дело в том, что компьютерная память медленная, а выполнение инструкций быстрое. Поэтому если условный переход зависит от значения, лежащего в памяти, то процессор во время ожидания, пока из памяти «подгонят» нужное значение, может начать выполнять инструкции той ветки, которую он считает более вероятной. Эти инструкции выполняются «секретно», их результаты не видны до тех пор, пока не произойдёт реальная подгрузка ожидаемого значения из памяти и процессор реально не убедится, что выполнение таки-пойдёт по ожидаемой ветке.

Если выполнение реально пойдёт по нужной ветке, побочные эффекты «секретно» выполненных операций публикуются процессором и становятся видимыми другим инструкциям. Если же выполнение не пойдёт по нужной ветке, спекулятивно выполненные команды аннулируются, и их результат никому не виден.

Однако, эти отменённые команды могут всё же производить побочные эффекты, наблюдаемые из нашего кода. Если отменённая команда читала память, которая не была загружена в кэш процессора, то эта память грузилась в кэш процессора, и последующее обращение к ней было быстрее. Таким образом, можно судить о том, что же делала отменённая команда.

Каким образом можно это использовать? Мы можем в спекулятивно выполняемом коде в зависимости от считанных данных подгрузить в кэш различные куски памяти, и измерив время доступа к ним, решить, какие же данные были прочитаны.

Чем это отличается от обыкновенного чтения данных? Вот тут-то и проявляется ошибка в Intel'овских процессорах. Дело в том, что мы можем спекулятивно читать память ядра, которая нам недоступна. Ошибка заключается в том, что при спекулятивном чтении не проверяются права на доступ к памяти.

---

Итак, наш код выглядит следующим образом:

1. Мы выделяем участок памяти X, по длине больший, чем несколько линий кэша.
2. Мы сбрасываем кэш так, чтобы память X не была в кэше. ([Например, так](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1756825/276994).)
3. Мы определяем адрес в ядре, который мы хотим прочитать, и записываем его в указатель `p`. Мы пишем код вида

   ```
   if (data == 0)
   {
       byte kernelByte = *p;
       byte dummy = X[(kernelByte & 1) * CACHE_LINE_SIZE];
   }
   ```
4. В `data` мы кладём ненулевое значение, и вытесняем `data` из кэша.
5. Мы выполняем указанный код, после чего измеряем время доступа к `X[0]` и `X[CACHE_LINE_SIZE]`.

Что происходит? Весь код внутри `if` не выполняется в реальности, но выполняется лишь спекулятивно. Про спекулятивном выполнении чтение по указателю на память ядра завершается успешно. В зависимости от значения младшего бита спекулятивно прочитанного значения мы производим доступ к одной из двух кэш-линий. Таким образом, одна из кэш-линий окажется загруженной в результате спекулятивного выполнения.

Если время доступа к `X[0]` близко к типичному времени доступа к закэшированной памяти, то в спекулятивном коде было обращение к `X[0]`, и значит, `kernelByte & 1 == 0`. Если время доступа к `X[CACHE_LINE_SIZE]` близко к типичному времени доступа к закэшированной памяти, то в спекулятивном коде было обращение к `X[CACHE_LINE_SIZE]`, и значит, `kernelByte & 1 == 1`.

Таким образом, мы смогли прочитать один бит защищённой памяти. Далее, один за одним можно считывать информацию. На текущий момент скорости считывания составляют около 1-2 килобайт в секунду.

---

Процессоры AMD не подвержены атаке Meltdown. Если верить [информации от инженера AMD](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/694d99d40972f12e59a3696effee8a376b79d7c8),

> AMD processors are not subject to the types of attacks that the kernel
>   page table isolation feature protects against.  The AMD microarchitecture
>   does not allow memory references, including speculative references, that
>   access higher privileged data when running in a lesser privileged mode
>   when that access would result in a page fault.

---

Параллельно с описанной атакой Meltdown есть очень похожая, в некотором смысле более общая атака, известная как Spectre.

В ней «недоступная» память читается так же, но не через границы уровней доступа. То есть, читается не ядро, а память собственного процесса (или, возможно, даже другого процесса, бегущего с теми же правами!). Этой уязвимости подвержены уже и процессоры AMD, потому что блокировка спекулятивного выполнения на уровне процессора «не видит» границ между процессами, т. к. процесс — понятие уровня операционной системы.

Зачем может понадобиться читать память своего же процесса? Например, для выхода из «песочницы». Код на JS в браузере обычно бежит в том же процессе, с теми же правами, а контроль над тем, чтобы JS не читал память за границами положенного, возложена на код, который проверяет выход индексов за границы диапазона. Как мы уже видели, выход индекса за границы диапазона возможен даже при контроле значения индекса при спекулятивном исполнении кода.

---

Обе атаки полностью пассивные, «молчаливые», поэтому на текущий момент не существует защиты или метода обнаружения атак, который мы как пользователи смогли бы использовать. Единственный способ защититься от Meltdown — ждать 
патча операционной системы.

Патч для Meltdown заключается в том, что из виртуального пространства процесса операционная система убирает память ядра. Это замедляет системные вызовы, но исправляет данную проблему.

Майкрософт выпустила патч против Meltdown для Windows 10 3.01.2018 как [KB4056892](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056892/windows-10-update-kb4056892). Убедитесь, что он у вас поставлен (если у вас, конечно, Windows 10). Это можно сделать, например, [при помощи PowerShell](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4073119/protect-against-speculative-execution-side-channel-vulnerabilities-in):

```
PS > Install-Module SpeculationControl
PS > Get-SpeculationControlSettings
```

Apple включила защиту от Meltdown в [iOS 11.2, macOS 10.13.2 и tvOS 11.2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208394). Проверьте вашу версию системы, если у вас Мак или i-устройство!

[Обновления для Ubuntu](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2018/01/04/ubuntu-updates-for-the-meltdown-spectre-vulnerabilities/) практически готовы, и ожидаются 9.01.2018 (или раньше, если получится). Не пропустите их.

---

Одна из неприятностей данных уязвимостей состоит в том, что атаку при определённых условиях можно проводить даже из Javascript.
Чтобы защититься от атаки Meltdown из javascript'а других сайтов, можно его временно отключить до выхода патча, но вы же не станете этого делать? Патча на Spectre для операционной системы нет, и он невозможен: уязвимость нужно исправлять в браузере.

Производители браузеров тоже прилагают усилия, чтобы было сложнее воспользоваться уязвимостью из Javascript.

[Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/01/03/mitigations-landing-new-class-timing-attack/) включает изменения, направленные на борьбу с уязвимостью, начиная с уже вышедшей версии 57, и усиливает защиту в версии 57.0.4 (бета).

[Хром](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/ssca) выпустит изменения в JS-движке V8 23 января (версия 64), но уже начиная с сегодняшнего дня будет предупреждать об использовании подозрительного API. На сегодняшний день Гугл рекомендует поставить последнюю версию Хрома и включить Site Isolation.

[Edge и Internet Explorer](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/01/03/speculative-execution-mitigations-microsoft-edge-internet-explorer/) получили изменения, направленные на борьбу с использованием уязвимости, начиная с уже вышедшего обновления KB4056890.

Улучшения браузеров мешают JS-коду получить точное время для измерения времени выполнения участков кода. Это, к сожалению, не закрывает полностью атаку Spectre, потому что изобретательный взломщик может найти способ измерять время другими методами. Поэтому Spectre, на эмблеме которого изображено привидение, будет ещё долго появляться и пугать нас.

---

Небольшое обновление: в выпущенной сегодня (26.01.2017) версии Visual Studio компилятор C++ включает новый ключ `/Qspectre`, который защищает скомпилированные программы от утечки данных через Spectre. Официальное объявление [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/01/15/spectre-mitigations-in-msvc/).)

---

Литература:

- [Project Zero, Reading privileged memory with a side-channel](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.de/2018/01/reading-privileged-memory-with-side.html)
- [Wikipedia: Meltdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability))
- [Geektimes: Новогодние подарки, часть первая: Meltdown](https://geektimes.ru/post/297029/)

---

Отдельное спасибо участникам @PashaPash и @Arhad, обсуждение с ними очень помогло прояснить общую картину и яснее понять проблематику.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71272/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-----meltdown).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Вот Ричард Столлман (основатель GNU) в одном из своих интервью сказал, не так давно, что в новых процессорах интел (кажется 7й серии) специально предусмотрен бэкдор, привет от правительства. Как Вы думаете о чём он мог говорить? Спасибо

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko: Например, он мог говорить об этом: [(1)](https://semiaccurate.com/2012/05/15/intel-small-business-advantage-is-a-security-nightmare/), [(2)](https://3dnews.ru/957829). Но уточнить лучше у кого-нибудь, более близкого к RMS.

Answer (score 18):

## В чём она заключается

*Внимание: текст ниже является донельзя утрированным и однобоким описанием работы процессора, в котором опущены многие важные детали. Однако это вынужденная мера для упрощения понимания сути атаки.*

### 1. Многопоточность там, где её не ждут

Все относительно современные процессоры выполняют данные не последовательно, команда за командой, а параллельно, кучей команд за раз. Это называется *суперскалярная архитектура*.

Однако любой параллелизм ломается ветвлениями (условиями, циклами и заходами в функции). Процессор не телепат, а потому не знает, куда именно пойдёт выполнение на очередной развилке. Поэтому он отслеживает, куда выполнение идёт чаще всего, и упреждающе помещает в параллельное исполнение команды именно этой ветки. Это называется *спекулятивное исполнение*.

Но процессор может и ошибаться, а потому все операции с регистрами и памятью в этой ветке перенаправляются во временное хранилище, так называемые *временные регистры*, содержимое которых записывается по назначению только при удачном переходе по ожидаемой ветке. В противном случае их содержимое отбрасывается.

Иными словами, весь выполняемый на упреждение код как бы сидит в «песочнице». И вот тут инженеры Intel допустили оплошность с целью оптимизации. Мол, если запись при упреждающем выполнении невозможна до известного процессору момента, то и все проверки безопасности можно отсрочить до того же момента — всё равно в случае чего данные будут бесследно отброшены.

Если бы инженеры знали, как они жестоко просчитались насчёт понятия «бесследно». Да, временные регистры абсолютно изолированы. Но у инструкций, выполняемых на опережение, имеется доступ не только к регистрам, но и к такой долгоживущей штуке, как **кэш**.

### 2. Сага о кэше

Кэш — это место, куда процессор временно складывает копии фрагментов оперативной памяти. Зачем он это делает? Всё просто. Оперативная память — штука крайне медленная, требующая сотни тактов на чтение одного байта. Потеря сотни тактов на каждый чих — непозволительная роскошь, да и из всей оперативной памяти программе, как правило, требуется совсем немного. Поэтому всю память условно разбивают на череду блоков по 64 байта каждый, а процессор снабжают небольшим (32КБ) количеством сверхбыстрой памяти, в которую он копирует те из блоков, что пытается читать программа. Блочность используется в предположении, что программа будет не скакать по оперативной памяти, а располагать данные компактно.

Вроде бы всё понятно и очевидно. Ах, да, кэш можно выборочно (поблочно) очищать для возможности получения наисвежайших данных из оперативной памяти. И ещё, если нужного блока в кэше ещё (либо уже) нет, команда-инициатор обращения приостанавливается и ждёт свои сотни тактов, пока блок не будет готов.

### 3. В гостях у проктолога, или используем стандартные средства нестандартным способом

Вы ещё не заметили ничего необычного? Значит вы не хакер (в исконно-благородном смысле этого слова). Ведь если принять каждый блок в кэше за один бит, а его пустоту/полноту за ноль и единицу соответственно, то мы получим прекрасное хранилище данных. Кратковременное, конечно, — до близжайшего массового сброса переключением задач, — да и объём подкачал. Но всё равно оно прекрасно.

Вы спросите: чем? Да тем, что к этому «хранилищу» имеют доступ инструкции из опережающего выполнения, упомянутого в начале (далее ОП)! То есть получается следующая воистину гениальная картина:

1. ОП, с одной стороны, имеют неподконтрольный и неограниченный доступ **ко всей** оперативной памяти (включая память ядра ОС, лежащую в верхнем диапазоне адресов). Ведь, как было сказано выше, все проверки будут выполнены позднее, когда настанет черёд проверки взятия условного перехода и записи изменений в регистры и память. А пока за нами никто не следит, мы с ОЗУ наедине — спасибо вам, инженера Intel!
2. С другой стороны, ОП имеют доступ к кэшу. Записать туда, конечно, ничего нельзя (это кэш чтения, а не записи), но можно сделать из него вышеописанное «хранилище» (заранее сбросив его) и производить чтение из определённых блоков памяти, отправляя их в кэш (мы условились, что это запись единичных бит в хранилище). С кэшем мы тоже наедине — ведь выполнение опережающее, а потому нас пока как бы и нет. То, что нас потом, возможно, отбросят, неважно — мы уже успеем поиграть с кэшем.

А на стыке этих двух вещей рождается поистине грандиозная *атака по побочным каналам*, позволяющая втихаря читать любую память, включая привелегированную, и отправлять её содержимое наружу. Осталось решить только две проблемы:

- как впоследствии читать из такого «хранилища»,
- как быть с посланным вдогонку прерыванием о нарушении страничной защиты; ведь неизбежно настанет момент сохранения временных результатов, при котором и вскроется наше переступление границ памяти.

### 4. Практическое использование

Первая проблема решается достаточно легко. Для этого достаточно пробежаться по всей той памяти, которой соответствуют использованные для «хранилища» записи кэша. Те блоки, которые не были тронуты (то есть как бы обозначают ноль) будут считываться значительно медленнее (помним про сотни тактов?), чем те, которые были принудительно предзагружены (то есть обозначают единицу). Если время доступа вообще неприличное, значит у нашего процесса истекло время исполнения и его вытеснили другим — повторяем запрос. Ну а точное время выполнения команды можно узнать у самого процессора с точностью до такта, благо есть соответствующая ассемблерная команда.

А вот у второй проблемы есть целых два решения, которые и известны как те самые *Meltdown* и *Spectre*:

1. Можно вообще плюнуть на исключение, благо степень параллелизма у современных процессоров большой, и мы спокойно (если повезёт) успеем прошерстить блоки памяти и восстановить переданное число. **Это Meltdown**.
2. Можно обмануть процессор, пустив выполнение по неожиданной для него условной ветви. Тогда исключения не возникнет в принципе, так как всё исполнение будет ошибочно-излишним. Ну а про побочный эффект где-то в районе кэша никто никогда и не узнает. **Это Spectre**.

Вот и вся суть обеих нашумевших уязвимостей. Кстати, это не гипотетические изыскания, а практичные вещи, с использованием которых исследователи спокойно копировали ядерную память стабильным потоком в пару килобайт в секунду.

## Как защититься

Если вы пользователь — то никак. Уязвимость слишком низкоуровневая.

Если вы разработчик программ или операционных систем — сбрасывайте участки кэш-памяти с чувствительными данными перед передачей управления стороннему коду.

Если вы разработчик микрокода в компании Intel — перенесите все проверки правомерности доступа с этапа применения команд на этап опережающего исполнения, как уже давно сделано у AMD. И не тяните с выпуском обновления микрокода.

Comment: Я бы более акцентированно уточнил, что сами чужие данные в доступные атакующему процессу линии кэша не читаются. Обновляют кэш *свои* данные, но по тому, какие свои адреса (естественно данные по этим адресам) обновлены можно вычислить биты данных, которые были по чужим адресам (в  которые и лезет meltdown)

Comment: Защититься просто, так же как и от любого другого трояна. Не качать и не запускать неизвестно что.

Answer (score 10):

Найдено на самом деле **две разных** уязвимости [с похожим механизмом но с совершенно разными последствиями](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com.by/2018/01/reading-privileged-memory-with-side.html):

## [Meltdown - Rogue Data Cache Load](https://meltdownattack.com/meltdown.pdf)

Подвержены [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/facts-about-side-channel-analysis-and-intel-products.html) и [некоторые из ARM](https://developer.arm.com/support/security-update).

Позволяет читать память ядра из юзермода. Прикрывается только патчем на OS, который перестает мапить память ядра, что бьет по производительности (и вызывает промахи кэша при системных вызовах).

- Позволяет процессу без ограничений читать память других процессов.
- Позволяет коду в одной виртуальной машине читать память хоста и других виртуальных машин.

Последнее - и есть основная проблема. Затронуты все хостеры, включая Amazon и Azure.

Иcправления:

- [Windows KB4056892](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056892/windows-10-update-kb4056892)
- Linux - ядра 4.14.11, 4.9.75 и будущее 4.15.
- MacOS - 10.13.2/10.13.3

Никакое "отключение JS" не помогает. Апдейта микрокода не будет. Единственный вариант - патч на операционку, который достаточно сильно бьет по производительности на IO-intensive workload (сеть и базы данных). В играх - никакой разницы.

Долгосрочные последствия: Интел выпустит новые исправленные процессоры, на 30% быстрее<sup>*</sup> которые раскупят намного быстрее, чем 8-е поколение. Хостеры, предоставляющие VM на исправленных процессорах, поднимут цены.

## [Spectre - Bounds Check Bypass + Branch Target Injection](https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf)

Подвержены Intel, AMD и ARM.

Позволяет обойти проверки вида `if (x < array1_size) y = array1[x];` при доступе к массиву в рамках *одного процесса*, выполняя код в том же процессе.

Основная проблема:

- позволяет коду на JavaScript обойти защиту и читать **всю память** процесса-браузера.

Исправления ожидаются со стороны уязвимых приложений:

- [Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/01/03/mitigations-landing-new-class-timing-attack/) v57.
- [Хром](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/ssca) v64.
- [Edge и Internet Explorer](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/01/03/speculative-execution-mitigations-microsoft-edge-internet-explorer/) - [KB4056890](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056890/windows-10-update-kb4056890).

Исправления браузеров никак не отключают сам Branch Prediсtion. Они снижают точность `performance.now` и временно отключают `SharedArrayBuffer` (был использован как таймер авторами атаки для Chrome). И, наверное, переписывают подверженные уязвимости проверки.

Долгосрочные последствия: Пострадают, прежде всего, разработчики браузеров. Всем, кто запускает в своем процессе сторонний код, придется очень аккуратно бороться с возможностью прочитать память всего процесса.

Comment: Правда, по поводу атакуемости AMD и ARM, следует отметить, что авторы отчета о [Meltdown](https://meltdownattack.com/meltdown.pdf)  пишут --  *`"However,  for both ARM and AMD, the toy
example as described in Section 3 works reliably, indicating that out-of-order execution generally occurs and
instructions  past  illegal  memory  accesses  are  also  performed"`*

Comment: @avp именно поэтому в моем ответе и написано, что Meltdown работает только на Intel, а Spectre - на Intel, AMD и ARM. Вот вам цитата из отчета по Spectre: Unlike Meltdown, the **Spectre attack works on nonIntel
processors, including AMD and ARM processors.**
Furthermore, the KAISER patch [19], which has been
widely applied as a mitigation to the Meltdown attack,
does not protect against Spectre`

Comment: То, что **Spectre** работает на всех 3-х в одном и том же процессе совершенно очевидно. Речь о том, что оптимизированная версия Meltdown также *возможно* будет работать с памятью ядра на всех.

Comment: @avp сорри, невнимательно прочитал коммент. да, но товарищи из AMD заявили, что не будет, т.к. проверка доступа у них происходит до чтения памяти и не подлежит реордеру. К сожалению, приходится верить им на слово. ARM, кстати, подвержены meltdown, по крайней мере новые Cortex-ы. Сейчас допишу в ответ.

Comment: *Прикрывается только патчем на OS, который перестает мапить память ядра, что бьет.* — куда бьет?

Comment: @АндрейNOP зоркий глаз :). исправил. пост, кстати, устарел, производители OS/CPU умудрились придумать патч на spectre (по крайней мере на один из вариантов)