# Как защититься от Meltdown и Spectre?

Tags: linux, windows, безопасность, macos, уязвимости

Как защититься от уязвимостей Meltdown и Spectre?

В идеале хотелось бы получить ответ для операционных систем Windows (7, 8, 10), macOS и популярных Linux дистрибутивов (Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Debian, Fedora, ...)

Comment: ждать обнов. или покупать недырявое железо)

Comment: Для винды - ждать "вторника патчей", для линукса уже, вроде бы, коммит в ядре есть

Comment: Так обновление ведь уже есть для Windows, на хабре даже тест до него и после выкатили.

Comment: Используйте процессор Pentium MMX.

Comment: @Visman Счеты надежнее. В звукоизолированной комнате (а так же с изоляцией от любых электромагнитных волн). Лучше в вакууме.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767237/191482  - в принципе написано

Comment: Купите железо на Itanium или Эльбрус.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чём смысл уязвимости Meltdown?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766862/%d0%92-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb-%d1%83%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-meltdown)